# Can I do custom complicated group by in a Django QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I need to do a sum of a certain column grouped by date and month. In SQL (postgres), it would look something like this:

```
select sum(amount) from somewhere group by extract(year from date), extract(month from date)
```

Can this be expressed as a Django `QuerySet`? Seems to me like it can't, but I don't really want to resort to plain old SQL. Any other ideas are welcome.

Seems like it might be possible using `queryset.query.group_by`, but I haven't had any luck with that - a working example would be welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `extra` method to add in the year and date values before doing the aggregation.

```
Somewhere.objects.extra(select={'year': 'EXTRACT(year FROM date)',
                                'month': 'EXTRACT(month FROM date)'}
                       ).values_list('year', 'month').annotate(Sum('amount'))
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of it this way!

Comment: Just a note, for **PostgreSQL** users it's more efficient to do: `.extra(select={'date':"date_trunc('month', date)"})...` . It gives you a date for the first day of each month.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Complex lookups with Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and [Generating aggregates for each item in a QuerySet](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset).